# Changing color of breadcrumb in materailize css

Tags: css, material-design, materialize, breadcrumbs

How do I change the color of breadcrumb text and arrow in materialize css. I can do it by applying appropriate classes but I am unable to change the color of the arrow mark in the breadcrumb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This Costom CSS changes the Arrow color.

```
.breadcrumb:before {
    color: #00ff00;
}
```

This is for the Text

```
.breadcrumb, .breadcrumb:last-child {
   color: #00ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When changing the color of anything in Materialize, it is best to use `!important` after the color:

```
background-color: #ffffff !important;
```

This typically works.